# How to resize a Canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, resize

I'm writing a WPF app that has a `Canvas` in it. This canvas will be custom rendered at runtime. It's sort of like a game in that it needs to be measured in pixels. I need to be able to set my `Canvas` to 478x478 pixels (client rectangle size). I don't want any scaling or other resolution-independent steps to take place on my `Canvas`.

I'm not sure if this is possible in WPF, since its nature is to be resolution independent. My questions:

1. How do I resize my `Canvas` at runtime (function to call?)
2. When I resize my `Canvas`, is the renderable area (the client rectangle) going to be that size? If not, how can I resize it to make sure the client rectangle is a specific width/height?
3. Is it possible to set the width/height of the `Canvas` in Pixels? How does the resolution-independent aspect of WPF interfere with what I'm trying to do?
4. When I resize my `Canvas`, will other controls resize appropriately as they have been designed to do in the WPF designer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any elements positioned in a canvas will not resize or reposition based upon the size of the canvas. So I don't think there's any advantage to setting the size of the canvas. Maybe you should just set a fixed size of the window instead.

Otherwise, just set the Canvas.Width, Height, and ClipToBounds=True and you have a fixed sized canvas that positions its child elements with X/Y coordinates.

Also you should be sure to set SnapsToDevicePixels=True on the canvas so that child elements will have crisp pixel-aligned bounds.

Comment: +1.  If you need the inner elements to fit to the constraints of the canvas, then the canvas is probably not the thing to use.  A grid with manually set dimensions would be better.

Comment: A bit old, use a Viewbox that wrap the Canvas yes.

Answer (score 6):

resizing is cake:

```
MyCanvas.Width = 350;
MyCanvas.Height  = 450;
```

this sets the size, you CAN render to coordinates outside of this, but it will be clipped. You can wrap your canvas inside a scroller to allow the user to see what is outside the height/width of the canvas.

as for the rest of your questions, i think you can see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611427/wpf-canvas-height-in-pixels) for your answers

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP: This code will resize the canvas, but not set it to 350x450 pixels. WPF doesn't use pixels as size units, but 96th parts of an inch; this code sets the width to 3.64in x 4.68in.

Comment: I set the size to 478x478 but I did not notice any other controls positioned relative to the bottom of the canvas changing. Perhaps changing the width/height doesn't force the main window to redo the layout? Also keep in mind that I'm setting Width/Height in my Canvas' constructor. I hope that's not too early.

Comment: when you position something in the canvas, its coordinates are relative to the canvas. they dont move automagically. you would have to loop through the child collection and manually adjust. :(

Answer (score 4):

Update 2020: on WPF .NET CORE: If the `Canvas` is a child of a `Viewbox`, the content is automatically scaled to the `Viewbox` height and width.

```cs
  <Viewbox Stretch="Fill"
           Width="50"
           Height="50">

     <Canvas>
       <Path.... />
     </Canvas>

  </Viewbox>
```

Comment: Holy moly... Its like a magic box! :)