# How to make resizable canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize a Canvas in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168698/how-to-resize-a-canvas-in-wpf)

I need to make resizable canvas in WPF, just like in windows paint. There isn't any resize property. Do i need some extra controls to make it? I also would like to connect then to some scrollbars, so if canvas would be too big, scrollbars will be enable to scroll the canvas.

Comment: It is not direct duplicate, the pointed thread has different goals: the question there was to resize the canvas to be logically fixed-size and rescalable-with-preserved-aspect-ratio to actual size needed, while here the author wants to make it resizable with scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canvas is just a container that will allow you to define default controls, etc. within that vehicle.  The canvas, then, must sit within a higher containment which is usually just a user control.  The user control provides the resize properties.

What I would highly suggest is you watch [these videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/wpftutorials?feature=watch) to learn more about WPF before you get much farther into whatever it is you are building.